# Install already compiled Memcached on another server

Tags: server, centos, installation, memcached, compiled

I would need to install Memcached on a server for which I don't have root rights.

- Is it (legally) possible to install it on another server (i.e. a
  CentOS virtual machine) and then bring the "compiled executable" on
  the original server?
- If yes, how do I avoid libraries and other dependencies issues?

I would like to avoid contacting server admins if possible as this translates in high waiting times.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible as long as you compile the dependencies into the `memcached` binary.
This implies disabling shared and building a static binary.

You can find someone having experience doing the same in [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/memcached/P4qMK4upyMk):

So the relevant steps are:

> 1. got latest libevent from: http://www.monkey.org/~provos/libevent/
> 2. build libevent as follows: 
>      (cd in libevent directory first) 
>      a. configure --prefix=/home/hduin/ots/libevent-1.4.13-build 
>      b. make install
> 3. in latest memcached directory: 
>      a. configure --with-libevent=/home/hduin/ots/libevent-1.4.13-build 
>      b. edit Makefile and add -static to LDFLAGS and -lrt to LIBS 
>      definitions 
>      c. make